# How to display defaultValues the first time a PreferenceActivity is started?

Tags: android, preferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I've defined my preferences in an xml file, preferences.xml. I've also got a SettingsWindow class which extends PreferenceActivity. I've set the android:defaultValue attribute on my preferences in the xml file but they don't appear the first time the app is launched. How do I load the default values defined in the xml file into the SettingsWindow the first time the activity is launched?

Comment: Give us a little code to work with so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what's going on. I had defined my preferences.xml file and associated `PreferenceActivity` without specifying defaults and ran that in the emulator. Later on, I added the `defaultValue` tags to the xml file. When I deployed to the emulator, it wasn't the first time the preferences had been loaded so the `defaultValue`s were skipped. Deleting the app's data and uninstalling\reinstalling the app fixed the issue.